# Is there active development going on IBatis.Net DataMapper?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, ibatis, datamapper, ibatis.net

Is there active development going on IBatis.Net DataMapper? Do they have version for .Net 3.5. I saw lots of activity on iBatis Java DataMapper as they are planning to release iBatis3 with annotation support. What is the status of its .Net counterpart?

Comment: Saw this http://www.mail-archive.com/user-cs@ibatis.apache.org/msg02942.html - so I don't think there will be a release any time soon. You can checkout the latest source and build yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In May/June 2010, the iBatis team left Apache and continued under a new name and a new home. You can read the announcement on the [old page](http://ibatis.apache.org/).

iBatis is now called MyBatis and the repositories (Java and .net) are hosted on Google Code.

- [new website](http://www.mybatis.org)
- [new mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mybatisnet-user)
- [Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/mybatisnet/)

There is [no official .net release yet](http://www.mybatis.org/dotnet.html):

> This is the core data mapping framework for .NET. Please be patient. We're updating the release for the MyBatis.NET Data Access Framework. Until it's ready, we recommend building from source.

...but at least [there is happening something in the source code](http://code.google.com/p/mybatisnet/source/list).